# Is it appropriate to use Cox regression when risk of event is higher at the start of study?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, cox-model

as per title, like to check if it is appropriate to use Cox regression when the risk of event appears to decrease with follow-up time?

If it is not appropriate, what model should I be using instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it not be? Cox regression assumes a baseline hazard function that can change over time in any way you want.

The more important question is whether the effect of model covariates stays proportional over time. I.e. in a standard Cox model, if those in category A have a 50% lower hazard rate than those in category B at the start of your follow-up, they should also have a 50% lower hazard rate later on. Of course, this is hard to check this when you only have a small number of events happens in each small time interval and one should not immediately get concerned if the Kaplan-Meier plots do not look exactly as one would expect. On the other hand, if this changes substantially over time, one can also have time varying covariates and/or interactions between time intervals and certain coefficients in the model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. @Björn Do you mind looking at my other question: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318187/problem-with-cox-regression)